# Getting SFINAE to work with `is_callable` on an overloaded function object

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, c++17

Consider the following function object `l`:

```
auto l = [](auto x){ x.foo(); };
```

I can successfully `static_assert` that it is callable with a type that has a `.foo()` member function:

```
struct Foo { void foo(); };
static_assert(std::is_callable<decltype(l)(Foo)>{});
```

I would now like `std::is_callable` to evaluate to `std::false_type` if I use a type that does not have a `.foo()` member function:

```
static_assert(!std::is_callable<decltype(l)(int)>{});
```

Unfortunately, the above `static_assert` results in a compilation error:

```
prog.cc: In instantiation of '<lambda(auto:1)> [with auto:1 = int]':
prog.cc:8:44:   required by substitution of 'template<class TF, class ... Ts> 
                struct is_callable<TF(Ts ...), 
                    std::void_t<decltype (declval<TF>()((declval<Ts>)()...))> 
                > [with TF = <lambda(auto:1)>; Ts = {int}]'
prog.cc:17:50:   required from here
prog.cc:12:24: error: request for member 'foo' in 'x', which is of non-class type 'int'
 auto l = [](auto x){ x.foo(); };
                      ~~^~~
```

---

I also tried implementing my own `is_callable` by using `std::void_t` as follows, getting the same compilation error:

```
template <typename, typename = void>
struct is_callable : std::false_type { };

template <typename TF, class... Ts>
struct is_callable<TF(Ts...),
    std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<TF>()(std::declval<Ts>()...))>>
    : std::true_type { };
```

I was under the impression that the `std::false_type` fallback would be chosen if the expression inside `std::void_t<decltype(/* ... */)>` was not valid due to SFINAE.

- **Why is this SFINAE not taking place here, resulting in a compilation error?**
- **How can I achieve my desired behavior?** *(i.e. evaluate to `std::false_type` if calling the overloaded function object is ill-formed)*

  - Please note that in my real use case I will not have access to the implementation of the *function object* on which I am performing the `is_callable` check.

[**live example on wandbox** *(C++14 compliant)*](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/yRTHaoQ6vECN2vhp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your lambda does not constrain it's​ arguments with sfinae. Your lambda is callable with anything, but triggers hard compilation errors when instantiated with these arguments.

To get the desired effect, put constraints on the return type:

```
auto l = [](auto x) -> void_t<decltype(x.foo())> { x.foo(); };
```

That way, the `is_callable` trait will yield the correct result.

Comment: Ah, I understand the issue now - thanks. Is there any way of achieving my desired behavior without constraining the lambda?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo You're asking if there is a way of constraining the lambda without constraining the lambda.

Comment: @Barry: I am asking if it's possible to detect whether or not the instantiation of the body of an unconstrained generic lambda would be ill-formed *(without producing an hard error)*

Comment: Nevermind - after thinking about it and reading related material I realized I'm basically asking for "speculative compilation", which will very probably never be a part of C++.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this SFINAE not taking place here, resulting in a compilation error?

Because `l` is callable with everything - the compilation error occurs when its body is instantiated, which happens outside of the *"isolated environment"* where SFINAE is taking place.

Constraining the lambda [as shown by *Guillaume Racicot*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42739960/598696) will fix the issue:

```
auto l = [](auto x) -> void_t<decltype(x.foo())> { x.foo(); };
```

*(Note that `void_t` is being used here as `x.foo()` is not being returned by the lambda.)*

---

> How can I achieve my desired behavior?
>   *(i.e. evaluate to `std::false_type` if calling the overloaded function object is ill-formed)*

If the function objects' signatures are not properly constrained, **there is no way of achieving your desired behavior**.

Being able to do that would require compilers to implement some sort of *"speculative compilation"* which is undesirable due to the difficulty of implementation.

More information in this article: [**"Diagnosable validity"**](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2016/05/10/diagnosable-validity/).

> There is no way to check it from within C++, and there is not going to be any: it has been clearly laid out, that compiler vendors cannot be forced to implement a “speculative compilation” and backtracking from arbitrarily deep template instantiation failures.

And in this discussion: [**"Asserting an expected compile-time failure"**](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!searchin/std-proposals/test$20if$20an$20error/std-proposals/ir1Jq6mtuiE/Lw5fvGlvwpEJ).

Comment: Why the downvote? Guillaume's post excellently answered my first question, but not the second one.

Comment: How did he not answer your second question? That's the `-> void_t<...>` part. This answer is mostly just repeating his, just with more **excessive**  *formatting*.

Comment: @Barry: my second question is then unclear - I will update the OP. What I wanted is to detect whether or not the instantiation of an arbitrary overloaded/template *function object* is ill-formed or not. Sure, in my minimal example I can just constrain the lambda - but that is not always the case for my **real** *problem*.

Comment: @Barry: adding the constraint made me understand why an hard error was being produced. It also however made me wonder if there's any way of achieving the same behavior by "looking at the body" of the *function object*, which is closer to my real use case. The articles/discussions I found and linked in my answer explained why that's not possible. I found that information very valuable, so that's why I decided to add another answer to my own question.